# Within, between or overall R-square for random effects in Stata

Tags: stata, econometrics

I'm performing a random effects analysis on panel Data, and I haven't been able to find an answer to the question, which R-square should I look at: within, between or random?

I know that for fixed effects I have to use within, but what about for random effects?

I am using Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random effect estimator (GLS estimator) is a weighted average of between and within estimators. In Stata, the default is random effect and you need to use R-squared: overall. As specified [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/auur.html), R-sq: within  is not correct for fixed effect and there are alternatives to correct that in Stata. For example you need to use R-square from the one provided by either `regress`or `areg`. Also, see [here](http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.pdf) for details.

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/imeus/traffic, clear

xtreg fatal beertax spircons unrate perinc

or 

xtreg fatal beertax spircons unrate perinc, re
```